# Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject error when binding to observable collection inside Revit dockable panel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await, revit-api

I'm currently working on a dockable panel inside Revit where I want to show a list of families in a TreeView.
Because our collection of families is rather large, and located on a network drive the load times can become quite long, especially when working via. VPN. Therefore I wanted to create a loading animation and unfreeze Revit while it is loading.

I decided to do that with async/await which I'm not very good at or used to using.

Right now I'm showing the loading icon, loading the list and hiding the icon like intended, but whenever I click the TreeView to browse the families I get the

> Must create DepedencySource on same Thread as the Dependency Object

I've gathered through posts similar to mine that I'm creating the list in a wrong thread (outside the UI) which causes the error, but I don't understand how to fix it.

The dockablepanel is running with C#, WPF and MVVM inside Revit. I'm creating and loading the list of families in the ViewModel which has a property 'DetailItems' that is bound to the view. For ease of use I'm using Fody.Weavers to handle the OnPropertyChanged events.

I tried using a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke without luck. I also tried using a background worker, and an 'ItemCache' but I can't get it to work.

**TL:DR;**
I'm getting a 'Must create DepedencySource on same Thread as the Dependency Object' error when binding an observable collection that I get with an async/await task. The view is a dockable Revit Panel that runs with C#, WPF and MVVM.

My ViewModel looks like this:

```
namespace CommonCode48.DockablePanels.FamilyBrowser.ViewModel
{
    public class DetailFamilyViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public bool LoadIsVisible { get; set; }

        public string SearchText { get; set; }

        private readonly BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        public ObservableCollection<Item> DetailItems{ get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemCache { get; set; }

        public DetailFamilyViewModel()
        {

            GetFamilyItems();
        }

        private async void GetFamilyItems()
        {
            //Start loading
            LoadIsVisible = true;

            //Start and wait for items to load 
            await Task.Run(() => ImportItems());

            //stop loading
            LoadIsVisible = false;

        }

        private void ImportItems()
        {
            var itemProvider = new ItemProvider();

            DetailItems = itemProvider.GetItems(@"J:\a_Revit\2021\Detalje");
            
        }
    }
}
```

and the itemprovider that finds all the files from a path:

```
namespace CommonCode48.DockablePanels.FamilyBrowser.Commands
{
    public class ItemProvider
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Item> GetItems(string path)
        {
            var items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                

                var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);

                foreach (var directory in dirInfo.EnumerateDirectories())
                {
                    var item = new DirectoryItem
                    {
                        Name = directory.Name,
                        Path = directory.FullName,
                        Items = GetItems(directory.FullName)
                    };

                    items.Add(item);
                }

                foreach (var file in dirInfo.EnumerateFiles())
                {
                    InteropBitmap thumbImg = ShellFile.FromFilePath(file.FullName).Thumbnail.BitmapSource as InteropBitmap;


                    var item = new FamilyItem
                    {
                        Name = file.Name,
                        Path = file.FullName,
                        FamImage = thumbImg
                    };

                    if (item.Name.Contains(".rfa"))
                    {

                    items.Add(item);

                    }

                }

                return items;
            }
            else
            {

                return items;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The `FanImage` property is of type `InteropBitmap` which is a `DependencyObject`.
If you bind DependencyObjects to the UI, they must have been created on "the UI thread" due to the thread affinity of DependencyObjects (i.e. all UI elements in WPF).

They are created on a non-UI-Thread, since a routine invoked with Task.Run runs on a threadpool thread.
You need to somehow refactor the code so that at least these bitmaps are created on the UI thread.

Comment: @lidqy Thank you - I think what I was missing was the fact that the image was the DependencyObject an not the collection it self. At least now I know what to work on!

Comment: @Orace It actually did! Thank you! It was solved by using thumbImg.Freeze(); before storing it in the items collection. Feel free to add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. I think my mistake was that I didn't understand the fact that the image was the DepedencyObject that needed freezing.